# Read XML files in SSIS

Tags: xml, ssis

I have a folder in the path `E:\path\Source\Books`. In that folder, there are 4 Books.xml files.

[image]

Each file looks like

[image]

Scenario:

Need to loop all files and process all the books in those files in SSIS package.

This is my package:

[image]

The outer foreach loop is of `File Enumerator type` and gets the each `file url` and store in the variable `User::Book`

The inner foreach loop is of `Foreach NodeList Enumerator` which loops and gets each book nodes.

[image]

But i'm getting an error while running this package.

> error : data at the root level is invalid

[image]

I need to get the book node from each xml and store it in a variable. How can I achieve that. Please correct me in this package.

Answer (score 0):

Two points to be aware of here:

1) The NodeList enumerator is failing on `<?XML VERSION="1.0"?>`. You should probably remove that line before running the XML through the ForeachLoop.

2) Your OuterXPathString has the wrong symbol. You should be using `/books`.